# ClojureScript reader tagged literals undbound fn error

Tags: clojurescript, reader

I am trying to utilize the tagged literal future on cljs. I have created
the folowing data_readers.clj

{dbz/l debuz.utils/cmlog}

And in src/debuz/core.cljs I required the file that contains the cmlog function:

(ns debuz.core
  (:require [debuz.utils]))

Then tested with this line of code

#dbz/l "This text is printed from src/debuz/core.cljs. Go ahead and edit it and see reloading in action."

And I get the undbound fn error:

#dbz/l "This text is printed from src/debuz/core.cljs. Go ahead and edit it and see reloading in action."
                                                                                                              ^--- Attempting to call unbound fn: #'debuz.utils/cmlog

Implying that the debuz.utils was not required ?
What am i missing here?
 I use the latest figwheel template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-1194

should rename to data_readers.cljc